# electron js doese not load jquery properly

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a web page and when I open it in chrome or fireFox, everything is fine, but when I try to open it in electron js with `window.loadURL()` it comes up with lots of errors because the jquery has not loaded.
Ive tried so many things (injecting js, adding jquery script tag and ...) but the main problem is some of events in those pages are related to `document.ready` and they are screwed

whats the problem and how should I fix it?

ps: lots of pages has this problem, but a url to test:
[online.agah.com](https://online.agah.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems nobody is interested, but however if someone had the same problem, the answer is use the webview instead of loading url in the window.

when the url loads in the webview, magically everything is fine.